# dealing with (possible) alert box on a webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, alert

I just started learning Python and decided to automate some tasks in my job that involve interacting with a website and Google Sheets. At some point, when I click the "next" button on the webpage, an alert box may appear with some information or may not appear at all. If it appears, I want to get the alert information and restart the loop. If the alert does not appear, I want to proceed with the code. The thing is, when there is an alert, my code works okay, but when there isn't an alert, I get a `TimeoutException` and can't proceed. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? I've tried using try and except, but it didn't work either (or maybe I didn't do it correctly).

```py
pyautogui.leftClick(1815, 585) #NEXT
alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
if alert in not None:
   alert = driver.switch_to.alert;
   alert_text = alert.text
    eproc = alert_text[-21:]
    sheet.update_cell (line, 14, eproc)
    alert.accept()
    pyautogui.hotkey('Alt', '1')
    time.sleep(4)
    continue    
else:
    #code to be executed if there is no alert
```

I also tried this but got a TimeoutException:

```py
alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
import selenium.common.exceptions as selexcept
while True:
    try:
        alert = WebDriverWait(driver, >10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        if alert is not None:
            alert = driver.switch_to.alert;
           alert_text = alert.text
            eproc = alert_text[-21:]
            sheet.update_cell(linha, 14, eproc)
            alert.accept()
            pyautogui.hotkey('Alt', '1')
            time.sleep(4)
            continue    
    except selexcept.TimeoutException:
         #code to be executed if there is no alert box
```

Comment: Can you please add some screenshot or the exact issue where you are seeing failure? Also, what kind of alert is it? (this is needed for making the code flow generic to handle it wisely).
For more to give you some insights on it, you need to implement polling mechanism to handle timeouts and alerts. In your case polling is the Issue!